# Hadwiger-Nelson problem in higher dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, real-analysis, graph-colorings

Given a positive integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we define the Hadwiger-Nelson graph $\text{HN}_n$ by

1. $V(\text{HN}_n) = \mathbb{R}^n$;
2. $E(\text{HN}_n) = \{\{v_1, v_2\}: v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } |v_1-v_2| = 1\}$.

Is it true that the clique number $\omega(\text{HN}_n)$ equals $n+1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: A nice, pure question.

Comment: Could you provide known clique upper bounds, and chromatic lower+upper bounds? At least $\ \omega(HN_1)=2\ $ and $\ \omega(HN_2)=3,\ $ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The moral reason is that cliques are 1-skeletons of regular simplices.  If you want convincing quickly then it's straightforward to show inductively that there is exactly one clique in $\mathbb R^n$ of order $n+1$ up to the obvious symmetries, because when you go up a dimension you have exactly two choices for where to place the extra point, and can't take both of them because they're not the correct distance apart.

As a crude upper bound we have $\chi(\mathbb R^n) \leq (\sqrt n + 1)^n$.  Tile $\mathbb R^n$ by cubes of side length $1/\sqrt n$, give a $(\sqrt n + 1) \times \cdots \times (\sqrt n + 1)$ block of cubes $(\sqrt n + 1)^n$ different colours and extend periodically.